# Should I use gerund here or the infinitive?

Tags: infinitivo

I want to say: Learning spanish is hard.

I figure I can say:

Aprendiendo español es muy dura.

or

Aprender español es muy dura.

Or are they both appropriate? Google translate gives me the latter but I know that you can use gerund on its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just the second one.  When a verb is used as a noun, it needs to go in the infinitive.  Also, as infinitives agree in the neuter (whose adjective form is the same as the masculine): "Aprender español es muy **difícil**". Typically you'll also want to use *difícil* as *duro* typical means *hard* as in *solid* and contrasted with *soft* or *bland*, rather than *easy*.

Using the gerund leaves a feeling like something is missing, that is to say *Aprendiendo español es muy difícil … aprender también el portugués.* (It's hard to learn Portuguese *while* learning Spanish).  Without it, the English would be "It (what?) is very hard while learning Spanish", although if that "it" had already been mentioned, then it would make sense.

Comment: So you can use gerunds on their own in the beginning of a statement (I've seen it). For example "Nunca vas a terminar. Trabajando. " from here http://www.fluentu.com/spanish/blog/spanish-gerund/.  But it still has to follow previous statements that talk about a subject that it is involved in.

Comment: @munchschair I would be be careful using the infinitive as a command. It certainly isn't part of any of the dialects I'm familiar with (in Spain, you'll hear the bare infinitive for that — also considered incorrect — but the easiest way for commands if you don't want to conjugate is "a + inf" which is, AFAIK, universally recognized).

Comment: @munchschair In "Aprendiendo español, es muy difícil aprender también el portugués" note the syntactic structure changes. Now, "aprender también el portugués" is the subject, not "aprendiendo español". I daresay a gerund can never be a subject. Also, don't trust that page too much. It seems to be biased towards a specific regional dialect of Spanish, not a general one. I've found a couple of expressions there I would never use (and some I'd hardly understand)

Comment: My understanding is that this use of the gerund **is** common in north america (the USA and at least parts of México). But it is much less common anywhere else. Therefore this answer is right; the second is correct and the first is a regionalism.

Answer (score 3):

Second one is the correct answer. First one makes no sense.

> Aprendiendo español es muy dur**o**. ✘
>
> Aprender español es muy dur**o**. ✔

Notice the "o".